# Suppress SQL Output

Tags: sql, sql-server

When running a SQL query with output to text we typically get back output like this.

```
AssetID              Occurs
-------------------- -----------

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Since I am doing thousands of select statements to audit data in my table is there a way to suppress this output on SQL server?

Comment: Some developers commonly include SET NOCOUNT ON in all stored procedures, unless they really do want to know how many records were changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to suppress the whole block you've shown then you'd need to do:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

...

IF EXISTS(SELECT AssetId FROM Table)
BEGIN
    SELECT AssetId, Occurs FROM Table
END
```

Comment: Thanks.. So basically suppress output until we find the count were are looking for.

Cheers

Comment: `IF EXISTS` would be a better choice here.  It's not necessary to get the whole count just to check if it's > 0.

Comment: @Aaronaught - thank, of course you're right. +1 and I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

Prefix the query with:

```
set nocount on
```

to suppress to rowcount messages.  You can disable column headers in SSMS, under Tools -> Options - > Query Results -> Results To Text.

As for the rows themselves, you could suppress them by adding a clause like `where 1=0`, but then I wonder why you select them in the first place.

Comment: That turns the count off and gives output like this. 
AssetID Occurs 
-------------------- -----------